# Mutt and msmtp interoperability

Tags: email, mutt, posix, msmtp

I am working on configuring /mutt/ to send mail via /msmtp/. Strangely, if I user 
/msmtp/ from shell, all okay, that means, that `.msmtprc` is correct.
However, mail sent with mutt do not come.
I have this line in `.muttrc`.

```
set sendmail="msmtp"
```

How can I debug this problem?

EDIT:

I found, that if I send just text, like `msmtp 'my-email' <<< "Hello"`, it works.
But if I send fully builded email-header, it do not. Is it gmail politics or what?

Comment: Have you tried setting `set sendmail="/PATH/TO/msmtp"`?

Answer (score 2):

You should enter the full path to msmtp, like

```
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
```

You might also consider setting the mutt options

```
sendmail_wait
use_from
envelope_from
from
realname
```